# $kx$ is the number of wavelengths per $2\pi x$-length segment. But what is $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{k}$?

Tags: waves, vectors, wavelength

If $k$ is the wavenumber of a wave and $x$ is a length, then $kx$ is «the number of wavelengths per $2\pi x$-length segment». I have seen that the quantity $\vec{r}\cdot \vec{k}$ appear in many formulas in physics, but I have not been able to interpret it in a literal sense. Can you provide a useful literal interpretation of it?

Comment: Just like for any vector product, $a_x b_x + a_y b_y $ etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1 dimension I would formulate it a little different:
If $k$ is the wavenumber,
then $kx$ is the phase difference
between position $0$ and position $x$.
(Remember $2\pi = 360° =$ one period)

Then you can carry over this statement almost unchanged to 3 dimensions:
If $\vec{k}$ is the wavenumber vector (perpendicular to the wave fronts),
then $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}$ is the phase difference
between position $\vec{0}$ and position $\vec{r}$.
Here the scalar product correctly accounts
also for non-parallel vectors $\vec{k}$ and $\vec{r}$.

Comment: Sounds interesting. What do you mean by phase difference between two positions? I thought you only had phase difference between waves?

Comment: You also have phase difference between two positions of the same wave. $2\pi=360°$ phase difference e.g. means the positions are separated by one wavelength.